# Monitor Connections to Database

Tags: c#

How to monitor the connection being made by one of the website to a  SQL database? I would like to monitor the same from webserver using C sharp. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What database? SQL Server?

Comment: Though it could be oracle or any other.. but particularly I'm looking for SQL one

Comment: @amitdayama SQL is just the "way you talk to it". The exact DBMS is important for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could write yourself a stored procedure that queries the Master.dbo.Sysprocesses and master.dbo.Sysdatabases
to return all the current connections.

```
SELECT  spid,
        sp.[status],
        sp.loginame,
        sp.hostname, 
        sd.name As 'DBName', 
        [program_name] 'Client Name'   
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses sp 
JOIN master.dbo.sysdatabases sd 
ON    sp.dbid = sd.dbid
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the active SQL Server connections. Use following SP [sp_who](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx)